# Generating Random ASCII

Tags: c

I've Been trying to work on a very simple encryption routine , It should work like this :

-- Generate A Random Key of ASCII Characters (Just a permutation of the ascii table) 
 -- For Every char in the File to be encrypted , Get Its Decimal Representation(X) , Then           Replace it with the char at Index X at the key.

The problem is that It corrupts some files and I Have no idea why.
Any help would be appreciated.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
int main()
{
    int  temp,used[256];
    char *key,*mFile;
    long i,fSize;

    memset(used,0,sizeof(used));

    srand(time(NULL));

    FILE *pInput = fopen("Input.in","rb");
    FILE *pOutput = fopen("Encrypted.out","wb");
    FILE *pKeyOutput = fopen("Key.bin","wb");

    if(pInput==NULL||pOutput==NULL||pKeyOutput==NULL)
    {
        printf("File I/O Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    key = (char*)malloc(255);
    for(i=0;i<256;i++)
    {
        temp = rand()%256;
        while(used[temp])
            temp = rand()%256;
        key[i] = temp;
        used[temp] = 1;
    }
    fwrite(key,1,255,pKeyOutput);

    fseek(pInput,0,SEEK_END);
    fSize = ftell(pInput);
    rewind(pInput);

    mFile = (char*)malloc(fSize);
    fread(mFile,1,fSize,pInput);

    for(i=0;i<fSize;i++)
    {
        temp = mFile[i];
        fputc(key[temp],pOutput);
    }

    fclose(pInput);
    fclose(pOutput);
    fclose(pKeyOutput);
    free(mFile);
    free(key);
    return 0;
}
```

The Decryption Routine :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main()
{
    int  temp,j;
    char *key,*mFile;
    long i,fSize;

    FILE *pKeyInput = fopen("key.bin","rb");
    FILE *pInput = fopen("Encrypted.out","rb");
    FILE *pOutput = fopen("Decrypted.out","wb");

    if(pInput==NULL||pOutput==NULL||pKeyInput==NULL)
    {
        printf("File I/O Error\n");
        return 1;
    }

    key = (char*)malloc(255);
    fread(key,1,255,pKeyInput);

    fseek(pInput,0,SEEK_END);
    fSize = ftell(pInput);
    rewind(pInput);
    mFile = (char*)malloc(fSize);
    fread(mFile,1,fSize,pInput);

    for(i=0;i<fSize;i++)
    {
        temp = mFile[i];
        for(j=0;j<256;j++)
        {
            if(key[j]==temp)
                fputc(j,pOutput);
        }
    }

    fclose(pInput);
    fclose(pOutput);
    fclose(pKeyInput);
    free(mFile);
    free(key);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: no checks, no comments, no debug prints -> bad code -> behavior can be unpredicted

Comment: @pmod The code is simple , no comments needed.

Comment: Please provide the decryption code you're using since the problem could just as well be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make sure you use `unsigned char`; if `char` is signed, things will go wrong when you process characters in the range 0x80..0xFF.  Specifically, you'll be accessing negative indexes in your 'mapping table'.

Of course, strictly speaking, ASCII is a 7-bit code set and any character outside the range 0x00..0x7F is not ASCII.

---

You only allocate 255 bytes but you then proceed to overwrite one byte beyond what you allocate.  This is a basic buffer overflow; you invoke undefined behaviour (which means anything may happen, including the possibility that it seems to work correctly without causing trouble - on some machines).

Another problem is that you write mappings for 255 of the 256 possible byte codes, which is puzzling.  What happens with the other byte value?

Of course, since you write the 256-byte mapping to the 'encrypted' file, it will be child's play to decode; the security in this scheme is negligible.  However, as a programming exercise, it still has some merit.

There is no reason to slurp the entire file and then write it out byte by byte.  You can perfectly well read it byte by byte as well as write it byte by byte.  Or you could slurp the whole file, map it in situ, and then write the whole file in one go.  Consistency is important in programming.

Comment: Changed the buffer size to 256 (What da hell was i thinking ^_^)

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler But I don't get what you mean by writing the key to the encrypted file , without the key , how would this possibly be decrypted ??

Comment: @Ahmed Sherif: There's no need to store the entire key.  All you need to do is call srand with a unique seed value and save the seed.  The decryption program can then call srand with the seed value and generate the same sequence of pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: Without the key (or a reliable way of generating the key - see Carey's comment), you can't decrypt it, but by including the key in the encrypted file, you are telling the attacker how to decrypt the file. That's why it is not a secure mechanism. It will 'work'; it just won't keep things secret for very long. Also your mechanism for generating the permutation is not dreadfully efficient; it can take a while to find the 256th value. A better technique would be to initialize the array with `array[i] = i;` and then do a permutation of that (see Knuth or Bentley or numerous other places for that).

Comment: And yea i know it ain't that efficient but i just needed to code it fast. I Know some better algorithms but I just didn't matter with performance in this case.